# EF custom selector expression

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following simple scenario. I have a Customer class, which is defined in my edmx. I have an Order class as well, and a Customer can have zero or more Orders through its Orders property.

I defined an OrderCount property in my Customer class like this:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to easily write Select queries, which load the value of this OrderCount appropriately. I tried doing this in the Customer class:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Customer, Customer>> DetailSelector = c =>
        {
            c.OrderCount = c.Orders.Count;
            return c;
        };
}
```

And then the Select query:

```
var customersWithOrderCount = ctx.Customers.Select(Customer.DetailSelector);
```

However, this way I get an error, that the lambda with a statement body can not be converted to an Expression.
Then I tried to do this:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int OrderCount { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<Customer, Customer>> DetailSelector = c => Customer.LoadDetail(c);

    public static Customer LoadDetail(Customer customer)
    {
        customer.OrderCount = customer.Orders.Count;

        return customer;
    }
}
```

But this way when I execute the Select query I get the following exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Customer LoadDetail(Customer)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What would be the easiest way to do this?

UPDATE: Just for clarification, I am specifically looking for a way to do this with an Expression. So I do not want to load the Orders from the database, I just want to fill the OrderCount property.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit simplistic, but I think stays with a basic working design on the entities. The best way IMHO is to use .Order.Count. If you are pulling it from there, why not keep it there?

If you want to write select queries, include the value from Customers.Orders directly and the proper SQL will be generated for you. Otherwise I would personally include this value to be set in a CustomerRepository class right after I load the customer. Then you always get your customer from one place and you know its set (implies usage of the Repository Pattern of course)

Comment: Yes but I am using the Customer instances in a distributed scenario with WCF, and I do not want to load and send down the Orders to the client, only the count of them (and this is just a simple example, in the real application I have many other properties like this).